# mysql if exists giving error wrong syntax?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use IF EXISTS in MySQL but i keep getting syntax errors and I have researched for correct syntax but everything isnt working...

What i need is:
If query exists then UPDATE else INSERT new...

```
$queryString =  "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $ONCALL_TABLE WHERE uid='$contextUser' AND submitid='$submitid' AND submitstatus=3) THEN UPDATE $ONCALL_TABLE SET uid='$contextUser', start_time='$onStr', end_time='$offStr', amount='$amount' ELSE INSERT INTO $ONCALL_TABLE (uid, start_time, end_time, amount) VALUES ('$contextUser','$onStr', '$offStr', '$amount') END IF";
```

Error message:
Can't perform query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM timesheet_oncall WHERE uid='admin' AND submitid='136545' at line 1

Comment: You've [escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) `$contextUser` and the other variables injected into your SQL, right? Constructing queries without using placeholders is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REPLACE INTO` is what you need. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

In your case

```
REPLACE INTO 
$ONCALL_TABLE (uid, start_time, end_time, amount) 
VALUES ('$contextUser','$onStr', '$offStr', '$amount')
WHERE uid='$contextUser';
```

Assuming `uid` is a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE KEY`

**NOTE:** Since the code in your question contains SQL injection flaws I would recommend you to read this article. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: if exists (select ...) replace into ?